# XSLT 2.0 transformation via linux shell

Tags: java, shell, xslt, jar, saxon

I want to perform an XSLT 2.0 transformation by the use of command line executions. I heard that i could use the Saxon library by a shell command like:

```
java -jar sax.jar -input foo.xml -xsl foo.xsl -output bar.xml
```

Does anyone know how exactly I can achieve that goal?

By the way, i am not limited to Java. Any other shell solution is fine.

Comment: Be aware that a Sax parser does not perform XSLT. Sax parser parse XML in a stream and fire events. Saxon is an XSLT processor. Most of the time a XSLT processor does not stream. Saxon (in his commercial version) has streaming capabilities with the latest instructions provided by XSLT 3.0.

Comment: thanks for clarification of correct naming

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation of Saxon is online: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/commandline. So you need:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:foo.xsl -s:foo.xml -o:bar.xml
```

Comment: thanks alot. i also found this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/saxonb-xslt.1.html is that good too or what would you prefer?

Comment: The version of Saxon shipped with your Ubuntu distribution is probably rather old. It's probably better to download the most recent version (though if you're a beginner you probably won't notice much difference).

Answer (score 3):

Update: check solution 2 and 3 if your java is version 11 or later, where `.internal.` are not available anymore.

I just wrote [this bash script](http://rboci.blogspot.com/2012/10/command-line-xslt-20.html) to use com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline classes for transforming XML. Works with openjdk just fine. Not a solution for production use cases but handy for debugging.

P.S. took the idea from [this blog](http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/java-command-line-xslt-transformation/)

- SOLUTION 2: use [xalan command line](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html)
- SOLUTION 3: https://github.com/physikerwelt/xstlprocJ

Comment: It seems, like all `.internal.` stuff, it goes away after some time... So your bash script ends up with ClassNotFoundException with JDK 11

Comment: @OndraŽižka, you are right. I've updated answer with another solution. Do you think Java stopped to embed XSLT or rather we have no way to access it anymore?